# Getting friends status updates and comments using facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

Hi i am new in using facebook api

i want to get the friends status based on following criteria

```
Get all the friends details (name, uid, status_message, posted_date) whose status update has more than 15 comments/likes
```

following query is giving all friends status updates

```
 SELECT status_id, uid , message FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Above query returns all my friends updates but i want to include the comments and likes on those updates in the response so that i can check the count on my side

there are comments table and likes table also in the `api` both might have foreign key relationship with the status_id column

Can we write a full query with joins like `SQL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do JOINs in FQL, but you can approximate them with a multiquery:

```
{
  'status': 'SELECT status_id, uid , message FROM status 
         WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())',
  'comments': 'SELECT post_id, fromid, time, text FROM comment 
         WHERE post_id IN (SELECT status_id from #status)'
}
```